# Hibernate queries really save time compared with SQL?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate queries really save time compared with SQL? I can see a very similar level of complexity. It solves the object-tables mapping, ok, but it is the same level of detail or it is considered a higher level abstraction?

Comment: What do you mean by "saving time"? Hibernate comes with a performance penalty, but it's generally faster for programmers to write code with native objects instead of writing database queries.

Comment: save developer time I mean

Comment: @HectorGiraldezGarcia, If you are comparing with respect to time spent while writing the code, then it depends on the situation like if you are using criteria api then it might simply your complex queries but if you are using hibernate queries then it generally have same structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate will save time to develop software. Caching improves performance. But nothing can beat native sql performance .  ORM frame work helps in maintenance and sustainability with a performance over head compare to native sql using JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate and generally all the ORM tools uses cache mechanism to increase performance so for some cases it might gives you better performance then native sql. 
In addition there are lots of benefits using ORM then writing sql queries directly like security, less complication while writing big queries etc.

But you can not conclude in native sql vs hibernate in terms of performance in yes or no. see [Performance difference of Native SQL(using MySQL) vs using Hibernate ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731008/performance-difference-of-native-sqlusing-mysql-vs-using-hibernate-orm)